# Rendering issue in WPF window while dragging

Tags: wpf

I have WPF window in which my Direct3D engine render. WPF Window I start from my engine, which I develop on C++/CLI.
I have 2 displays and when I move window between them, part of the window became white and not update until I am not stop dragging it (like on screen shot).[image]
Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

It will be hard to post code here as it is a lot of code, but I will try:

I use managed C++ and unmanaged in one project:
So, I add .Net dll`s to have access to the WPF window:

```
Window^ wnd = gcnew Window();
wnd->Width = 1280;
wnd->Height = 720;
wnd->Show();
WindowInteropHelper^ helper = gcnew WindowInteropHelper(wnd);
HWND WPFHwnd = (HWND)helper->Handle.ToPointer();
HINSTANCE hinstance = (HINSTANCE)Marshal::GetHINSTANCE(this->GetType()->Module).ToPointer();
engine->SetHisnstanceHWND(WPFHwnd, hinstance);

engine->InitializeSystem(wnd->ActualWidth, wnd->ActualHeight);
```

engine - this is unmanaged class which incapsulates all work with rendering.
Further it is a stardard d3d rendering loop. Nothing special.
It render OK, but when I resizing or move window, it draw a part of it like this (with white). When I stop resizing or moving - all OK again.

My question is: is it possible to get rid of this effect or not?

**UPDATE:**

I hooked the wndProc if the WPF window and try to use UpdateLayout() when size changing, but this has no effect. Seems window is not react on any intervention.

Comment: Post some relevant code and see if you an reproduce the error on small testproject. The struture of your project does not seem clear: what is your D3D engine renderer? How does WPF relate to that, et.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like your engine is receiving WM_ERASEBKGND and it clears the window. After you release the window, it sends WM_PAINT and everything is clear again. That's what I believe might be happening.

In order to test this theory, you can handle that message and return true. Put that to your engine message handling routine:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
{
  PAINTSTRUCT pss;
  BeginPaint(hWnd,&pss);
  EndPaint(hWnd,&pss);

  return true;
}
```

You can use WinSpy++ to check out what messages are delivered to underneath window. If you want to see why the background is whited out, you can do it through ProcessMonitor and see what API calls are being issued. You're probably interested in API calls that include the color white.

Comment: I test it and can say that it works but only on half. Now when window is get out or display it not become white, but when I change its size the whole window still became white during changing its size. What can I do in this situation? Help me please to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tracked down the "source" who clears your window? Use WinSpy and look for all the messages that are generated on resize and analyze them. You should post your D3D engine loop too. How do you handle the resize in D3D? Note I am not too familiar with D3D, but integrating OPENL into WPF is something similiar. You should subscribe into WPF's SizeChanged event and perhaps trigger WM_PAINT on your HWND? Not sure.